# Mailchimp api showing error 'INVALID RESOURCE'

Tags: node.js

I have given the `email_address` to be req from the body but it still says:

> Error 404 INVALID RESOURCE

Here is my app.js file

```
const express=require("express");
const bodyParser=require("body-parser");
const path = require("path");
const https=require("https");
const app=express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/index.html");
})
app.post("/",function(req,res){
    var firstName=(req.body.firstname);
    var lastname=(req.body.lastname);
    var email= (req.body.email);
    var data={
        members: [
        {
            email_address:email,  //I have named the input tag as email
            satus:'subscribed',
            merge_fields:{
                FNAME: firstName,
                LNAME: lastname
         }
       }
     ]
    }
    const url="https://us21.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/{list-id}/members"
    const JSONData=JSON.stringify(data);
    const options={
        method: "POST",
        auth: "THIRSTYMOB:{api-key}"
    }
    const request=https.request(url,options,function(response){
    console.log("running");
    response.on("data",function(data){
        console.log("running");
        console.log(JSON.parse(data));
    })
})

    request.write(JSONData);
    request.end();
   

});
app.listen("5000",function(req,res){
    console.log("listening on");
});
```

I tried to use email which I have req from the body and then stored it in `email_address`.

So why does it still say that no email has been added and give the following error

Here's the error that is shown in the terminal:

```
type: 'https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/docs/errors/',
  title: 'Invalid Resource',
  status: 400,
  detail: "The resource submitted could not be validated. For field-specific details, see the              'errors' array.",   
  errors: 
      field: 'email_address',
      message: 'This value should not be blank.'
```

I have no idea where it is going wrong